# grails BIRT plugin deployment problem in linux

Tags: grails, birt

I integrate the BIRT plugin in my application. in the development environment (windows) it works fine. but my deployment is on a Linux server. i getting the application startup error about the engine initialization -  i trying to configure the path in a config properties file but it is still not working - do you have the experience in this deployment i'll be happy for you help.

Meni

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the file `birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip` in `/home/your_User/.grails/1.3.7/download`
and run:

```
install-plugin birt_plugin
```

It's very important to run all these steps with root privileges......